# "If you know what X is" or "if you know what is X"

Tags: grammar, dependent-clause

Recently I encountered the phrase "If you know what is QQ then(...)". The writer wasn't a native English speaker(neither me).

First, I thought it should be "If you know what QQ is ...". But then, I thought about the phrase: "If you know what is right..." I think the latter implies that you already know *what "true" is* and you should find/select an object. Or is it related to the fact that "true" is an adjective? Or is it just wrong?

So, I'm very confused. Can you help me?

I tried to search for it, however searching for "what is" in search engines is really difficult! The nearest questions are [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33092/what-it-is-that-is-versus-what-is) and [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69684/which-is-correct-if-any-please-let-me-know-what-do-you-think-or-please-le), but I don't think it's a duplicate.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.

Comment: In "If you know what is right...", *what* is the subject. In "If you know what QQ is", *what* is the object. The subject being *QQ*. These are two completely different *whats*.

Comment: We need to recognized when an intelligent question is asked. Even if the wording of the question itself may be simple. Voting to reopen.

Comment: fatih, Patience!